# javascript + css divs folding effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I've been looking online for this kind of effect for long time without having success.

It looks like there is a js script that changes dynamically the css `-webkit-transform: rotateY(deg)` property.

Is there anything online that does the same thing?

I hope somebody can share a similar script thanks.

#### If there is enough space it shows the boxes with no rotation:

[image: If there is enough space it shows the boxes with no rotation]

#### If there isn't enough space the script changes the rotation and get them closer to each other:

[image: If there isn't enough space the script changes the rotation and get them closer to each other]

Comment: please create an example of what you've tried!

Comment: Hi, this is what I achieved so far.

.panel-max-rotation {
 z-index: 900;
/*    value min is 180 max 45*/
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg);
}

Comment: Please create an actual example using CODE

Comment: Ok, sorry i'm new and I don't know how to use the platform, i'm trying to understand, thanks for your help.

Comment: no problem - but you can just try using the button to create a code example - the little paper with the <> inside of it - and add your JS, CSS, and HTML - then you'll be delighted that somebody will come along and alter your code for you :) good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example looks like a y-rotation. Heres a basic snippet of it.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/200?random');
  transition-duration: .35s;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px #000;
}

div:hover {
  transform: rotateY(70deg);
  transition-duration: .35s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: yes but i'm looking for a javascript script that dynamically change the rotten position. But I can't find nothing online.

Comment: aah, I understand what you mean. You can get this over different ways. One way could be to to flex all items inline so they need to collide if they are too much. And to check if a collision is incoming use `element.getBoundingClientRect();` Then you can give all cards the rotation.

Another way is if you know e.g. four cards have space in one line without rotation you say `if (cards.length > 4) { rotation }` (dummy code, dont work with copy and paste).

Comment: Hi is there a way to chat with you?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a library that can rotate or animate HTML Elements you can use [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). It's easy to use !!

Comment: You are welcome if it helps you, do not forget to vote up this answer!

Comment: I did vote up your answer already, I think in the library you shared with me there isn't the animation I'm looking for, but I thanks you anyways.